# Pass a value from h:outputLink to JSF after onclick event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, primefaces

I need to pass an integer to a JSF backing bean after `onclick` event on `h:outputLink`.

**Important :** I cannot use f:param to pass value as request parameters to the naviagating page as I am preventing default onclick behaviour of h:outputlink. *The control instead of navigating to page defined by href attribute, goes to a javascript function*.

Using Primefaces 3.0M3 snapshot with JSF 2.0

---

My code follows:

```
<h:outputLink id="#{item.id}" value="/itemDetails.xhtml" class="itemLink" >
      #{item.name}
</h:outputLink>


<script>
$(".itemLink").click(function(event) {
  showDetailsInDialog();// show the item details in dialog 
  event.preventDefault();// prevent the behaviour provided by href
});
</script>


<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="showDetailsInDialog" update="itemDetailsPanel" oncomplete="itemDetailsDialog.show()">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="....id of the item...." target="#{itemsList.selectedItem}"/>
    </p:remoteCommand>
</h:form>
```

I have a reusable `dialog` that displays the details of item selected from a itemslist. For this when the `h:outputLink` for an element is clicked the id of that item needs to be passed to JSF to render appropriate content in `dialog`.

As shown above If I can get the id of item in `remotecommand`, I can pass it to appropriate backing bean through `setPropertyActionListener`

Comment: If you are using PrimeFaces look at the `p:remoteCommand` component, it generates a Javascript function to invoke backing-bean method.

Comment: @BheshG: Thanks! Yes, I'm using primefaces & I also tried using remotecommand but I couldn't figure out how to pass value from `h:outputLink` to `f:setPropertyActionListener` inside of `p:remoteCommand`. If you could assist me with a sample code that would be great!

Comment: Consider that I have the value in `h:outputLink` in a JSF backing bean.

Comment: Can you post your code (both the view and the bean)?

Comment: @BheshG: I have posted my code above. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can't use EL Expression for the id attribute. Like `<h:outputLink id="#{item.id}"`, have tried it? Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316790/dynamic-ids-in-jsf-seam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `p:commandLink` instead of `h:outputLink` as follows -

View -

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink value="#{item.name}" action="#{myBean.fetchItem()}" update="detailPanel" oncomplete="detailDlg.show();">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.itemId}" value="#{item.id}"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Bean -

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{itemStore}")
    private ItemStore itemStore;

    private int itemId; //getter/setter
    private Item item;  //getter/setter

    public void fetchItem() {
        this.item = this.itemStore.getItemWithId(this.itemId);
    }
```

**Update:**

You can do that by using JQuery as follows -

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".itemLink").click(function(event){
                jQuery("#itemIdHI").attr("value", jQuery(this).attr("id"));
                remCom();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>

<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:inputHidden id="itemIdHI" value="#{myBean.itemId}"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="remCom" action="#{myBean.axnMethod()}" process="itemIdHI" update="detailPanel" oncomplete="detailDlg.show()"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Infact I was using p:commandLink earlier but I am now wanting to use outputLink inorder to create bookmarkable urls besides allowing the inverse click options like 'open in new tab'

Comment: I have got some hint for my case.. I can also use remoteCommand to pass value to backing bean from js. Rightnow, I cannot figure out how to supply/receive parameters to remoteCommand

Comment: @Marcos: I have updated the answer. I am not sure about whether it's the right way to do that but it seems to work. Basically, have a hidden-input (bound to the backing bean item prop using el) inside the form with the p:remoteCommand and use jQuery to update the value attribute of hidden input before invoking the remoteCommand. Also don't forget to process hidden input on remoteCommand invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) out. I have the same problems as you, but i solved it after reading [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s link.

For short, there's what u're talking abt:

***f:attribute:*** with the **h:commandLink** and **h:commandButton** tags you can also trigger a method of the backing bean using the **actionListener** attribute. With this you can also use the f:attribute tag to dynamically pass the parameters. Here is an example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Click here" actionListener="#{myBean.action}">
        <f:attribute name="attributeName1" value="attributeValue1" />
        <f:attribute name="attributeName2" value="attributeValue2" />
    </h:commandLink>

    <h:commandButton value="Press here" actionListener="#{myBean.action}">
        <f:attribute name="attributeName1" value="attributeValue1" />
        <f:attribute name="attributeName2" value="attributeValue2" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

*Those attributes can be retrieved using **getAttributes**() of the parent UI component, which on its turn can be retrieved by the **ActionEvent** passed by the **actionListener**.*

```
package mypackage;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import net.balusc.util.FacesUtil;

public class MyBean {

    // Actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void action(ActionEvent event) {
        String attributeName1 = FacesUtil.getActionAttribute(event, "attributeName1");
        String attributeName2 = FacesUtil.getActionAttribute(event, "attributeName2");

        System.out.println("attributeName1: " + attributeName1);
        System.out.println("attributeName1: " + attributeName1);
    }

}

package net.balusc.util;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class FacesUtil {

    // Getters -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static String getActionAttribute(ActionEvent event, String name) {
        return (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get(name);
    }

}
```

*The variables **attributeName1** and **attributeName2** now should contain the values attributeValue1 and **attributeValue2** respectively.*

*Take care that each attribute name should be unique and should not overwrite any default component attributes, like "id", "name", "value", "binding", "rendered", etc.*