# How to perform JSF setPropertyActionListener before javascript onclick event

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here is the deal: I have a dataTable populated by a list in my managed bean. What I want is to open a simple primefaces dialog with the selected object's infos and I am trying to do so by using a setPropertyActionListener and a onclick event.

```
                <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Resumo" onclick="dlg1.show();"
                                 type="button" 

                                 >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado}"
                                                 value="#{artigo}" />

                </p:commandButton>
```

And the dialog

```
        <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Resumo - #{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado.titulo}" 
                  widgetVar="dlg1" 
                  dynamic="true">
            #{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado.resumo}
        </p:dialog>
```

The thing is that the action performs before the setPropertyActionListener takes effect. So the dialog pops up with no object at all.

What should I do to make sure the setProperty performs before the action thus setting my object.

**Update**

An other topic here helped answer this. 
[Pass a value from h:outputLink to JSF after onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215001/pass-a-value-from-houtputlink-to-jsf-after-onclick-event?rq=1)

and the result is that:

```
<p:commandLink id="basic" value="Resumo"
                               oncomplete="dlg1.show();"
                               update="@form">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado}"
                                                 value="#{artigo}" />

                </p:commandLink>
```

and the dialog

```
<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Resumo - #{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado.titulo}" 
                  widgetVar="dlg1" 
                  dynamic="true">
            #{consultaArtigoBean.artigoSelecionado.resumo}
        </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `oncomplete` attribute which will get fired after the ajax postback. 
Further update the dialog via the `update` attribute.

[Execute p:commandLink action before onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370309/execute-pcommandlink-action-before-onclick-event/9371116#9371116)