# How to set the id of h:selectBooleanCheckbox dynamically?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have

```
<wai:collectionIter value="#{listModel.listRows}" valueVar="listRow" odd="odd" even="even" styleVar="rowStyle">
  <tr class="#{rowStyle}">
    <td>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{listRow.rowSelected}" disabled="#{detailModel.readOnly}">
        <c:set target="#{component}" property="id" value="#{listRow.rowData.name}"/>
      </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </td>
    <ui:insert name="columnData"/>
  </tr>
</wai:collectionIter>
```

(where wai:collectionIter is a custom tag)

but the corresponding html code looks like

```
<td>
  <c:set target="javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox@10cd160" property="id" value="BusinessUnitNumber"></c:set><input type="checkbox" name="searchForm:j_idt100" /
</td>
```

I must say that c:set target="#{component}" comes from an example I found elsewhere ...

As I'm not a JSF expert and assuming that it is correct, I expected that the resulting html was something like this:

```
<td>
  <input id="BusinessUnitNumber" type="checkbox" name="BusinessUnitNumber"
</td>
```

Is it completely wrong or do I miss something else?

Thank you for any help.

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a standard JSF iterating component instead of a vague custom tag. E.g. `<ui:repeat>`:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{listModel.listRows}" var="listRow" varStatus="loop">
    <tr class="#{loop.even ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
                id="foo" 
                value="#{listRow.rowSelected}" 
                disabled="#{detailModel.readOnly}" />
        </td>
        <ui:insert name="columnData"/>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

It'll worry about uniqueness of the IDs. It will prepend the row index to the given fixed ID like follows:

```html
<tr class="odd"><td><input type="checkbox" name="formid:repeatid:0:foo" id="formid:repeatid:0:foo" /></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td><input type="checkbox" name="formid:repeatid:1:foo" id="formid:repeatid:1:foo" /></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><input type="checkbox" name="formid:repeatid:2:foo" id="formid:repeatid:2:foo" /></td></tr>
```

You *can* make it dynamic by `id="#{listRow.rowData.name}"`, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Francesco,

You try this:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{listRow.rowData.name}" value="#{listRow.rowSelected}" disabled="#{detailModel.readOnly}" />
```

Comment: Hello Bruno,sorry but I forgot a (important) piece of code in the first code-snipped. I added it now.

Comment: Francesco, when I was used jsf the component ids area dynamilly and you put configured id similar to code was posted by me. Try and return some doubt.

Comment: Bruno, I didn't really understand what do you mean, so I figured out you want that I put in your code anyway. `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{listRow.rowData.name}" value="#{listRow.rowSelected}" disabled="#{detailModel.readOnly}">    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. I did and now I get "javax.servlet.ServletException: Empty id attribute is not allowed"

Comment: The closest you will get your result will be something like searchForm:BusinessUnitNumber because searchForm works as a container and the ids will be nested. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316790/dynamic-ids-in-jsf-seam/326389#326389) explain better.