# JSF2 EL not displayed in components IDs

Tags: java, jsf

I have the following piece of code:

```
<ui:repeat var = "ctr" value = "#{bean.counterList}">
    <h:outputLabel for = "message#{ctr}" value = "#{appMessage['No #{ctr} :" />
<h:inputText id="message#{ctr}" value="#{bean.messageList}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The `counterList` is an `List<String>`. If the list contains `1, 2, 3` on the view thee should be 3 input fields with the ids : `message1, message2, message3`.

The EL has no effect in the **id** attribute and all the components receive just **message** as an ID. On the other hand, in the label's value, the EL works great.

I can imagine that this may be the desired behaviour but is there a workaround?

**UPDATE:**

I removed the `id` attribute and the `ui:repeat` is in charge of naming the id's now. From the source code I can see that the ID's generated are unique but now this warning is thrown:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=fm-story:j_idt103:0:j_idt54[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.)]
sourceId=fm-story:j_idt103:1:j_idt54[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not attempt to manually index the IDs of the components inside a fullworthy JSF iterating component like `<ui:repeat>`, `<h:dataTable>`, etcetera. This will only result in disaster as you experienced yourself. It will work inside a JSTL `<c:forEach>`, because it runs as being a view build time tag at the moment the JSF component tree is to be built, not at the moment the HTML output is to be generated. The `<c:forEach>` would also generate physically as much JSF components as is been iterated.

Just omit any EL from `id` attribute. The JSF component will worry about setting the right client ID automagically. Further, you can use `varStatus` attribute of the `<ui:repeat>` to get the current loop count and index. This way you don't need 2 lists. The count will show the current round. The index is mandatory in order to get/set the value of a `List<String>` by index. The `<h:inputText value="#{message}" />` namely won't work because the `String` class doesn't have a setter.

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputLabel for="message" value="#{appMessage['No']} #{loop.count}:" />
    <h:inputText id="message" value="#{bean.messageList[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

*(you can if necessary omit `var="message"` from the above snippet as it isn't used anywhere)*

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve is described here [Dynamic Id's in JSF/Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316790/dynamic-ids-in-jsf-seam) and here http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/jsf-using-component-ids-in-data-table.html

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked it, but the correct behaviour is going to be of the form:

```
<ui:repeat var = "ctr" value = "#{bean.counterList}">
  <h:outputLabel for="message" value="#{appMessage['No #{ctr} :" />
  <h:inputText id="message" value="#{bean.messageList}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The *component identifier* `message` is not going to change; the [*client identifier*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) (e.g. `fm-story:j_idt103:0:message`) will change on a per-row basis during lifecycle processing. The label component's `for` attribute algorithm will be able to find the input component using "message" as they share a naming container.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helps me but weirdly enough, it doesn't solve the problem. It seems that there is some weird behaviour when having a `List` in the `property` tag.. This is the error I'm getting: `NFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=fm-story:j_idt59:0:message[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.)]`

Comment: What type is `counterList`? The error probably has something to do with binding the list as the value of an input control instead of a mutable row property. The Expression Language doesn't know how to coerce a string to whatever `counterList` is and it wouldn't do you any good if it could because every row would be bound to the same value. A correct binding will generally look like `#{ctr.someProperty}`.

Answer (score 1):

its same issue that i had...
[How can i set id of h:panelGroup inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147771/how-can-i-set-id-of-hpanelgroup-inside-uirepeat)

you can't set the ids in the fly with ui:repeat (look at the link above)

You can use the`<c:forEach`

like this

```
<c:forEach var = "ctr" items = "#{bean.counterList}">
    <h:outputLabel for = "message#{ctr}" value = "#{appMessage['No #{ctr} :" />
    <h:inputText id="message#{ctr}" value="#{bean.messageList}" />
</c:forEach>
```

(BUT you should only be [well aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) of how JSTL works in Facelets)

Comment: Thank you! But all these input elements have to be saved in a `List` in the managed bean. I'm not sure if this process will work smoothly without JSF's `h:inputText`